# User.Identity.Name is empty in production environment

Tags: asp.net

i've an ASP.NET 2.0 web app. 
If i run in debug mode on my development machine, proprerty **User.Identity.Name** isn't blank, it return my name "MyDomain\myname".
If i deploy this same app into a Linux server with apache and Mono runtime, the User.Identity.Name is blank.

Where i'm wrong ?

EDIT: I don't know the type of authentication. I use the web.config 'as is' without modifyng nothing, i've also tried: `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`

Comment: Is your development machine also a Linux box with Apache and Mono runtime?

Comment: I would assume this has to do with the type of Authentication being used. Are you using Forms authentication?

Comment: Well, i don't know which type of authentication i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mono only supports the "None" and "Forms" authentication modes.
>   "Forms" is the authentication used by ASP.NET forms. "None" means that
>   no authentication is necessary. The unsupported options are "Windows"
>   and "Passport".

[Mono: Config system.web authentication](http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web_authentication)

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting anonymously to your app.

Assuming you're using forms authentication:
If you look in the system.web section of your config file, there should be a section like so:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <!-- deny anonymous -->
    <allow users="*"/>
    <!-- allow all authenticated -->
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

If you ensure that the `deny users="?"` setting is present Asp.Net will force users to be authenticated before allowing access to pages. This will ensure that the `User.Identity.Name` property is set.